# English Translation of the Quran with contextual explanation?

Tags: quran, tafseer, quran-translation, english

Through Google search, I've found a couple of English translations of the Quran recommended by scholars. Some editions are also easily available online. The ones I found are basically sentence-by-sentence translations from the Arabic words, at times with explanation of the origin/context of those words in Arabic language.

However, I believe that any kind of translation wouldn't serve me well until I can also read a short contextual explanation/purpose of those Ayats/Surahs based on Islamic history. Can anyone recommend how should I go by with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, this is going to be a matter of personal preferene. You can try multiple sites and see which one fits your needs better.

- [Altafsir](http://www.altafsir.com/) hosts a number of Qur'anic Commentary and translations. You can display the *tafsīr* of your choice through a drop-down menu. See example [here](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=74&tSoraNo=2&tAyahNo=2&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2).
- [Islam Awakened](http://www.islamawakened.org/) hosts a transliteration, a word-for-word translation, then a huge number of translations in a long list per verse. There is no Qur'anic Commentary but you may find the multiple translations displayed all in one page to provide a range of the possible meanings of a verse. See example [here](http://www.islamawakened.org/quran/2/2/default.htm).
- [QuranX.com](http://quranx.com/Tafsirs) hosts a number of tafsīrs, but you have to stick to one tafsīr at a time as it is not possible to change your choice once you are reading one. See example [here](http://quranx.com/Tafsir/Kathir/2.2).

Comment: Are these full translations or summaries?

Comment: @Medi1Saif — The tafsirs are a collection of what is already available in print, so it is a mixture of full translations (e.g., Al-Jalalayn, translated by Feras Hamza) and abridged translations (e.g., Ibn Kathir, translated a team that worked for Darussalam).

Answer (score 1):

There is a good and enriched online library in [www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org). You may find good books, article, and videos about history of that time as well as commentaries about Holy Quran. Go to following links:

https://www.al-islam.org/library/quran-commentaries

https://www.al-islam.org/library/general-quran-hadith